# Аналог copy con для powershell

Tags: powershell

Здравствуйте.
Столкнулся с вопросом имеет ли PowerShell свой аналог copy con. Нашел в [интернете](http://www.out-web.net/?p=755) сайт с примером, но выбивает ошибку синтаксиса. Не могу понять, что не так. Напишитепожалуйста свой простой пример (например,создание файла со скрипитом для вывода "Hello!" в консоль). 
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: покажите какую ошибку выбрасывает

Comment: спасибо уже разобрался

Comment: @SeniorAutomator, не могли бы Вы глянуть тему: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/578473/%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b0-powershell-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-vpn

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Итак начнем.
Сначала выбивало различные ошибки типа не распозано имя командлеп**а.
НО ФАЙЛ СО СКРИПТОМ СОЗДАЕТ**. Чтобы избежать ошибки связаной с незапуском скрипта, меняете правила сертификата executionpolicy.  [Или же используем один из способов запуска файла](http://www.securitylab.ru/analytics/461333.php).
Може вопрос и был глупым, все равно надеюсь поможет избежать другим подобных ошибок.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, посмотрите пожалуйста тему http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/578765/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8a%d1%8f%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%85-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b0-powershell