# ошибка скрипта PowerShell, проверяющего подключение VPN

Tags: powershell

Здравствуйте.
Возник вопрос связанный с ошибкой приведенной на рисунке. В чем проблема? Ведь после второй ошибки, скрипт выполняется?????
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так что здесь не так? Гуглил в интернете. но все не то. Мне действительно нужна помощь.

Comment: `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force` выполните вначале

Comment: @SeniorAutomator, а что он делает?

Comment: Прописал, но термиал ругнулся

Comment: Не знаю в чем проблема, но я нашел странную вещь. Откроя файл со сценарием,увидел что не била прописана перемнная $net, хотя я в терминале ее вводил при создании файла. Предупреждение убралось.

Comment: запустите от имени администратора (run as administrator) и выполните. если будут ошибки, то напишите тут об этом

Comment: Вас понял, попробую

Comment: @SeniorAutomator, все работает. спасибо.Не сочтите за наглость, но все же спрошу, не затруднит ли Вас глянуть тему http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/578765/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8a%d1%8f%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%85-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b0-powershell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сначала нужно выполнить `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force`, который позволяет запускать скрипты

Источник: «[Using the Set-ExecutionPolicy Cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ee176961.aspx)»<sup>[[архив](https://web.archive.org/web/20151125210222/https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ee176961.aspx)]</sup>.

Comment: огромное спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
if((Get-VpnConnection BeeVPN).ConnectionStatus -eq "Сonnected")
{ ... }
else
{ ... }
```