# Нужна помощь с разъяснением четырех строчек скрипта PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Здравствуйте. Есть скрипт, который сканирует порты:

```
filter Test-TcpPort {
### paramaters (1) (optional, default = 80): [int] port // что это, что здесь лишнее???
### object pipeline: [string] IP addresses and hostnames // что это, что здесь лишнее???
### output: ### [string] "$_ ## status" // что это, что здесь лишнее???
Param([int]$port = 80) // что это, что здесь лишнее???
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue" // избавляемся от ошибок, а от каких, например???
$socket = new-object Net.Sockets.TcpClient // присваиваем переменной сокет значение сокета???

$socket.Connect($_, $port) // подключаем сокет
if ($socket.Connected) // если подключен, статус- подключен, и мы отключ.его
{ 
   $status = "Opened" 
   $socket.Close() 
} 
else // иначе статус - отключен
{ 
   $status = "Closed / Filtered" 
} 
$socket = $null // зануляем переменную?????
write-output "$_`t$port`t$status" 
}   
$a = 'bing.com','yahoo.com','google.com'  // масив доменных имен
$a | Test-TcpPort // выполнение относительно них теста?
```

Скрипт не мой, но хотелось бы разобраться. Спасибо.

Comment: Я понимаю, что вопрос может и глупый для людей сведущих в этом, но хотя бы ответьте что - то

Comment: каких строчек конкретно  ?

Comment: @SeniorAutomator, 2-5, я их закоментил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> #### paramaters (1) (optional, default = 80): [int] port // что это, что здесь лишнее???
>
> #### object pipeline: [string] IP addresses and hostnames // что это, что здесь лишнее???
>
> #### output: ### [string] "$_ ## status" // что это, что здесь лишнее???

это просто комментарий и ни на что не влияет

> Param([int]$port = 80)

а это уже параметр, который по умолчанию, если ничего не предать, принимает значение 80, иначе то значение, которое передадите
например,

```
 >Test-TcpPort 
// $port == 80

 >Test-TcpPort -port=100 
 >Test-TcpPort 100 
// $port == 100
```

`[int]$port` принимает тип int, для того, чтобы пользователь не ввел данные, отличные от типа int, например `Test-TcpPort "aaa"` сразу выдаст ошибку

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо

Comment: как понять, что то просто коментарии? благодаря # как в простой cmd?

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, не будет ли для Вас обременительным, если я буду еще обращаться к Вам для консультации по PowerShell?

Comment: да, # - это комментарий. обращайтесь

Comment: еще раз спасибо

Comment: почему работаю именно с Вами? просто Вы первый, кто нормально ответил. И вт я так понмаю, на сегодня последний вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/579590/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-system-object-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf-system-management-automation-scri