# Не удается преобразовать System.Object[] в тип System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock, необходимый Process метод не поддерживается

Tags: powershell

Здравствуйте.
Есть код скрипта, который проверяет все IP для заданого хоста. Пример брал с [сайта](http://www.remoteshaman.com/programming/powershell/work-with-tcp-ip-network-with-windows-powershell-examples). Что означает ошибка описанная в топике. Конкретно третяя строка. Скажите, как это исправить и что означают закоментенные строчки. На сайте, как Вы могли сами убедиться, далеко не самое содержательное объяснение.

```
$hostname = "microsoft.com" ????
$result = [system.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName($hostname) // я так понимаю, переменной result типа DNS присв.имя хоста? 
$result.AddressList | ForEach-Object {$_.IPAddressToString} // что это?        
$name='remotehelp.pp.ua','remoteadministrator.pp.ua','moderators.pp.ua',
'itadmin.pp.ua','remotehelp.org.ua','remoteadmin.org.ua','rootus.org.ua',
'rootsupport.org.ua','techroot.org.ua','techsupport.org.ua' // масив хостов
$ns='ns1.server.biz' //что это?
$i=0 
while($i -lt $name.length) // что это?
{ 
 nslookup $name[$i] $ns // что это?
 echo '--------------------------------------------------' 
 $i++ 
}
```

Comment: Скопировал с сайта скрипт. У меня в Powershall он работает без ошибок. Вообще, откройте CMD и напишите `nslookup "microsoft.com" "8.8.8.8"` и не придется строить огород в powershall без нужды. (`nslookup "адрес сайта" "адрес днс сервера"`)

Comment: @AndrewB, так бы и сделал, да только мне сказано ознакомиться именно с написанием скриптов и есть источник. Поэтому и спрашиваю. А за Ваш ответ все равно спасибо, если бы сам делал - воспользовался именно Вашим ответом.

Comment: @AndrewB, может вопрос и глупый, но почему 8.8.8.8. Почему именно этот IP?

Comment: @MuscledBoy 8.8.8.8 - это DNS-server google-а

Comment: @MuscledBoy не очень понятен где вызывается ошибка, без трейса ошибки

Comment: @SeniorAutomator, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powershell работает с командлетами. Среди командлет существуют аналоги команд из командной строки (CMD).

Он командной строки CMD заметно отличается следующим:

- Есть возможность передавать результаты выполнения одних командлет в другие, фильтровать и сортировать результаты.
- Есть возможность вызывать статические функции .Net Framework

О других отличия погуглите, если потребуется.

Разберем ваш пример скрипта по строкам (первая часть)

```
$hostname = "microsoft.com"
$result = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName($hostname)
$result.AddressList | ForEach-Object {$_.IPAddressToString}
```

1. Объявление переменной.
2. Объявление переменной (тип `IPHostEntry`). Вызов функции .Net Framework [System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(string hostName)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.dns.gethostbyname(v=vs.110).aspx). Эта функция возвращает результат типа [System.Net.IPHostEntry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.iphostentry(v=vs.110).aspx)
3. Берем из результата значение [AddressList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.iphostentry.addresslist(v=vs.110).aspx). На самом деле это не одно значение, а список значений [System.Net.IPAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.ipaddress(v=vs.110).aspx). Далее выполняем командлет, который перебирает список этих System.Net.IPAddress, преобразовывает каждый из них в строку и выводит ее в консоль.

Вторая часть скрипта

```
# или воспользоваться циклом если нужно проверить несколько хостов:
# Массив доменных имен для проверки
$name = 'remotehelp.pp.ua','remoteadministrator.pp.ua'

# Сервер имен который нужно опросить
# если нужно опросить системные ДНС, оставьте пустое значение
$ns='ns1.server.biz'

$i=0
while($i -lt $name.length)
{
    nslookup $name[$i] $ns
    echo '--------------------------------------------------'
    $i++
}
```

1. Объявление переменной (массив строк)
2. Объявление переменной
3. Объявление переменной
4. Цикл от 0 до количества строк минус 1 (потому, что `-lt` означает меньше, а не меньше или равно) в первой переменной (1). Я укоротил список, поэтому в данном случае цикл выполнится 2 раза
5. Вызов [утилиты командной строки](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc725991(v=ws.10).aspx) nslookup с параметрами "строка из списка `$name`" и "адрес сервера DNS из переменной `$ns`". Эта утилита выводит какой-то результат в консоль.
6. Вывод в консоль текста "----------"
7. Увеличение переменной `$i` на 1, чтобы выбрать следующую строку из списка `$name`

Пример скрипта выбивает из колеи тем, что в нем смешаны не только два примера, но и разный синтаксис (для .Net Framework, для командлет, для утилиты командной строки).

Надеюсь, что ответ поможет разобраться в Powershell

Comment: Я искренне Вам благодарен. Ваш ответ действительно облегчил понимание. Правду говоря, редко кто захочет написать столь насищенный ответ. Еще раз спасибо. Позвольте еще к Вам обращаться если возникнут подобные неясности?

Comment: При возникновении новой проблемы создайте новый вопрос, либо вносите дополнения в существующий (если он не решен). Постараюсь ответить.

Answer (score 1):

```
$hostname = "microsoft.com" 
$result = [system.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName($hostname) 
# $result.AddressList - это  массив объектов, который резолвит имя $hostname
$result.AddressList | ForEach-Object {$_.IPAddressToString}   #   Проходим по этому массиву и на экран выводим только IP

$name='remotehelp.pp.ua','remoteadministrator.pp.ua','moderators.pp.ua',
'itadmin.pp.ua','remotehelp.org.ua','remoteadmin.org.ua','rootus.org.ua',
'rootsupport.org.ua','techroot.org.ua','techsupport.org.ua' # ЭТО список хостов, просто массив
$ns='ns1.server.biz' # DNS-server 
$i=0 
while($i -lt $name.length) # итерация по списку хостов
{ 
 nslookup $name[$i] $ns # just look up 'host' using 'server'
 echo '--------------------------------------------------' 
 $i++ 
}
```

пример вывода цикла

```
PS> nslookup 'remotehelp.pp.ua' 'ns1.server.biz'
nslookup : *** Request to UnKnown timed-out

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  91.212.139.3

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
```

Comment: не очень понятен где вызывается ошибка, без трейса ошибки

Comment: спасибо, немного понятнее стало. Кстати, ошибка исчезла